# Multiple CakePHP applications on the same server

Tags: php, session, cakephp, authentication

I have multiple CakePHP applications running on my server. The issue is that if you login to the application at www.myserver.com/app1, it will think you are logged in when you go to www.myserver.com/app2 and fail when trying to pull up your information.

Is there any way to isolate the sessions or specify that they belong to the specific application?

I've tried adding this line in core.php
$prefix = 'connect_app1_';

It doesn't seem to make any difference. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do this in your `Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Session', array('cookie' => APP_DIR));
```

Comment: That seems like it would be on the right track, but for some reason I am now getting these errors: Notice (8): Undefined index: cookieTimeout [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 465]
Notice (8): Undefined index: timeout [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 474]
Notice (8): Undefined index: timeout [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 507]
Notice (8): Undefined index: timeout [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 507]

Comment: I think it just has to be done in core.php instead, I posted the code I used in an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Dave, you were on the right track.
I modified my `Config/core.php` file:

I replaced:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
));
```

With this:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'my_app1'
));
```

And it completely fixed the problem.